# Linq query with GROUP BY on multiple fields, SUM and COUNT

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to use a LINQ SQL to query my database.

Let's say I have some data that looks like this:

```
var1 var2 var3 qty
1    a    1a   50
1    a    1a   25
2    b    2b   10
2    b    2b   15
2    b    2b   10
3    a    3a   25
```

I know how to format my query in SQL. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3, count(*) AS count, sum(qty) As quantity
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY var1, var2, var3
```

In this case the output would be something like this:

```
var1 var2 var3 Count Qty
1    a    1a   2     75
2    b    2b   3     35
3    a    3a   1     25
```

How can I do the same thing with LINQ in vb.net

```
Dim groups = From j In MyTable
             Group By j.var1, j.var2, j.var3 Into g
             Select new {var1 = g.var1, 
                         var2 = g.var2, 
                         var3 = g.var3, 
                         quantity = sum(g.qty),
                         count = count(*)}
```

That's not quite right, but I think it's close. I don't understand the syntax of the group by in VB.NET.

Comment: I think you should use the `g` variable as you data source in the select.

Comment: Yes it's g. Actually I get a compilation error Definition of method 'g' is not accessible in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to group by an anonymous type, this is the syntax in VB.NET (note the `Key`):

```
Dim groups = 
    From j In MyTable
    Group By x = New With {Key .var1 = j.var1, Key .var2 = j.var2, Key .var3 = j.var3} Into g = Group
    Select New With {
        .var1 = x.var1,
        .var2 = x.var2,
        .var3 = x.var3,
        .quantity = g.Sum(Function(r) r.qty),
        .count = g.Count()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) like this:-

```
Group j By Key = New With { Key .Var1 = j.var1,
                            Key .Var2 = j.var2,
                            Key .Var3 = j.var3 } Into Group
Select New With { .var1 = Key.Var1,
                  .var2 = Key.Var2,
                  .var3 = Key.Var3,
                  .quantity = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.qty),
                  .count = Group.Count()
                }
```

Comment: Ah, this is why. I must use Group. Group is a keyword. Thank you.

Comment: @B413 - Any specific reason for unaccepting the answer? Just asking, it's your wish completely :)

Comment: I think you updated your answer because your code isn't working any more.

Comment: @B413 - It's not working now? I edited on that particular day itself. Yeah it had few issues earlier but by the time you checked it, it was fine. Anyways after so many days it happened so I was curious to ask :)