# Linq GROUP BY or manually grouping in a loop?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

Yesterday I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33364411/196526) on stackoverflow. Today I realize that if I do a GROUP BY I also need to create a new type of object.

Let's say I have some data that looks like this:

```
var1 var2 var3 qty
1    a    1a   50
1    a    1a   25
2    b    2b   10
2    b    2b   15
2    b    2b   10
3    a    3a   25
```

Here is my working LinQ query

```
From j In MyTable
    Where j.var1 = "xxx"
    Group j By Key = New With {Key .var1 = j.var1, Key .var2= j.var2, Key .var3 = j.var3} Into Group
    Select New With {.var1 = Key.var1, .var2 = Key.var2, .var3 = Key.var3, .qty = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.qty)}
```

Actually I use Entity Framework and the code look more like this

```
Dim foo = (From j In dbContext.MyTable
           Where j.var1 = anotherVariable
           Group j By Key = New With {Key .var1 = j.var1, Key .var2= j.var2, Key .var3 = j.var3} Into Group
           Select New With {.var1 = Key.var1, .var2 = Key.var2, .var3 = Key.var3, .quantity = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Qty)}).ToArray()
```

foo is a new type that doesn't exist in my generated Entities. But I have an entity generated by my entity framework that can contains these. It's MyTable itself. I use a GROUP BY only to sum a column of MyTable. I query a MyTable entities and I can put the result in a MyTable entity too.

My question are

1) Can I write something like this

```
Dim foo = (From j In dbContext.MyTable
       Where j.var1 = anotherVariable
       Group j By Key = New With {Key .var1 = j.var1, Key .var2= j.var2, Key .var3 = j.var3} Into Group
       Select New MyTable With {.var1 = Key.var1, .var2 = Key.var2, .var3 = Key.var3, .qty = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.qty)}).ToArray()
```

In this case do I need to explicitely write all the mappings ?

2) Should I change my mind. Do a simpler query without GROUP BY and try to group and sum in a VB.NET loop (For Each). Or two queries ? On to get all MyTable with a WHERE clause and another to group ?

```
Dim foo = dbContext.MyTable.Where(Function(p As MyTable) p.var1 = anotherVariable).ToArray()
For Each bar In foo
    'Code to group and sum or another query
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: No, the question is not the same. Actually the duplicate is a duplicate of the question I asked yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to instantiate `MyTable` in an LINQ to Entities query but you can simply enumerate the results of the projection with `ToArray` and then construct the entities with another `Select` call.